# Polymer svg iconset and performance with multiple same icon

Tags: performance, svg, polymer-2.x

I am using the polymer svg iconset and iron-icon element in my page. Lets say I have a large number if rows in a table and each row has a couple of icons in it (uses iron-icon). These icons are repeated in every row. When I inspect the DOM, I see that each iron-icon in each row has the same icon svg as part of the DOM (inside the shadow root of icon-icon). 
Isn't this a huge performance bottleneck? IE11 is slow in parsing DOM and this can cause further slowness. Would a font base icon set be more optimized here? Is Polymer's approach to use a svg iconset wrong?

Comment: Well, _do_ you have performance isues?

Comment: we are testing with IE11 and we do have performance issues there. Also, chrome lighthouse shows a heavy DOM alert.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the performance issue is not in the size of the DOM itself, but the JS API *interaction* with it. The way Polymer implements the icons, it acts as a polyfill for Web Components custom elements. What actually happens in older browsers that don't understand their declaration is that if you write

```
<iron-icon icon="search"></iron-icon>
```

a scripts cycling through the DOM replaces what are considered unknown elements with DOM elements the browser understands (You'd have to look in the DOM inspector to see what actually is used in a specific browser).

A more direct approach could be to use something that IE understands natively, for example the SVG sprite pattern. Include an invisible `<svg>` element that contains symbols

```
 <svg display="none">
     <symbol id="search" viewBox="..."><path d="..." /></symbol>
     ...
 </svg>
```

and reference them

```
<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#search"/></svg>
```

If you can achieve that when compiling the page server-side, it avoids the use of scripting in the client and should give a nice performance boost.

Even if your table cells are constructed client-side, adding these elements to the DOM directly might still be faster than first adding somesthing that a script has to replace later in a second run. (But that is only my guess without experience to back it up.)